# C# decimal places with integer operators

Tags: c#, string, format, decimal, int

So I have this code:

```
p.Value = 1;
decimal avg = p.Value * 100 / 10000;
string prntout = p.Key + " : " + avg.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(prntout);
```

But the program prints out 0, instead of 0.01. p.Value is an int. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change one of the literals into a decimal:

```
decimal avg = p.Value * 100m / 10000;
```

Now, to explain why this works:

Lets process the original line one operation at a time, substituting 1 for p.Value:

```
decimal avg = 1 * 100 / 10000; // int multiplication
decimal avg = 100 / 10000; // int division, remainder tossed out
decimal avg = (decimal) 0; // implicit cast
```

By changing 100 to 100m, it's now:

```
decimal avg = 1 * 100m / 10000; // decimal multiplication
decimal avg = 100m / 10000; // decimal division
decimal avg = 0.01m;
```

Comment: Side note: Decimal's literal type code is `m`, presumably for money.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `p.Value * 100 / 10000` is only using integer types, so evaluates according to [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) rules.

Change one (or more) of the parameters to a decimal and it will perform as expected:

```
p.Value * 100 / 10000m
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
decimal avg = p.Value * 100 / 10000;
```

to

```
decimal avg = Convert.ToDecimal(p.Value) * 100.0 / 10000.0;
```

Your previous versions used all integers.

Answer (score 0):

If P.Value is an integer you will probably lose the fraction on this line:

decimal avg = p.Value * 100 / 10000;

So you can do this:

decimal avg = (decimal)P.Value * 100 / 10000;

Hope it helps.